# Kotlin material design dialog get selected option

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design

I need to get selected option name (text) instead of position when I close my dialog but it keep returning item position.

`Code`

```
pType.setOnClickListener{
    val singleItems = arrayOf("Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3")
    val checkedItem = 0

    pType.text = null
    MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this)
        .setTitle(resources.getString(R.string.project_type))
        .setNeutralButton(resources.getString(R.string.cancel)) { dialog, which ->
            // Respond to neutral button press
        }
        .setPositiveButton(resources.getString(R.string.ok)) { dialog, which ->
            // Respond to positive button press
        }
        // Single-choice items (initialized with checked item)
        .setSingleChoiceItems(singleItems, checkedItem) { dialog, which ->
            // Respond to item chosen
            pType.setText(checkedItem.toString())
        }
        .show()
}
```

`Questions`

1. How can I get option text when I click OK in dialog?
2. By using `val checkedItem = 0` regardless of my selected option always `option 0` is selected, how can I avoid that?

Comment: `regardless of my selected option always option 0 is selected` you don't ever assign another value to it other than having it be zero the first time, so it _should_ do that.

Comment: @a_local_nobody thanks for not showing how to assign other value rather than 0! `it's fixed now`

Comment: there's no need to be rude about it. i'm simply stating that if you have something declared as a `val`, it can't change, that's the point of `val`. if you want to change it, then it should probably be a var, or you should read it from somewhere when you need it

Answer (score 0):

instead of:

```
pType.setText(checkedItem.toString())
```

try:

```
pType.setText(singleItems[which])
```

Comment: this was the correct one `pType.setText(singleItems[which])`

Comment: @mafortis you should mark this as an answer if it helped you out

Comment: @a_local_nobody it's not correct answer why should I mark it? I even provided right answer s/he doesn't want to update the answer why would I accept wrong answer?

Comment: ah, you're right, i thought it was correct